# PHP function called function almighty_function

Tags: php, function

I have this PHP function

```
function almighty_function($x, $y, $z) {

 if ($y != $z && $x == $y && $x == $z) {

    return "Success!";

 }

 return "FAIL!";

}
```

which set of values for $x, $y and $z for function will return "Success!".

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I never heard of almighty_function, and what are the values of $x, $y, $z.?

Comment: That's the question @MujahedAKAS, /facepalm.

Comment: I mean what values are being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
false, '0', ''
```

Both strings `''` and `'0'` are evaluated as falsey, however they are not equal to each other.

Similarly `true, 'foo', 'bar'` for any non-empty, non-`0`, and non-equal string values of `foo` and `bar`.

---

For more see the table: [Loose comparisons with ==](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

To avoid this sort of thing use strict comparisons with `===` and `!==`.